# docker-compose up -d wont start php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, fpm

im windows user.

i try to run laravel project with:

```
> docker-compose up -d (based on documentation)
```

all container running well except php-fpm
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrTJC.png)

> standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

when i running in server it running smoothly.

**Question**

please guide me to setting in windows envirovment.?

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. Could you provide a few more informations such as : a link to the "documentation" you are talking about, you docker-compose.yml file, your docker version, and you docker-compose version... this would be a good start!

Comment: "I'm a Windows user", "standard_init_linux: ... no such file or directory" is extremely frequently a line ending issue.